# C-clips removal and installation on spray equipment

Tags: woodworking, tools, wood-finishing, spraypainting

Dealing with C-clips when cleaning spray guns frustrates me.
I lose them, bend them, gouge my fingers, scratch my equipment, and sometimes give up.
Is there a recommended way of working with them that preserves your sanity?

Edit: Here is a picture :
[image]

Comment: How about a few pictures of your problem ones.  I never had problems with mine...

Comment: Depending on the exact type, there are some tools that make it easier, but usually those types are recommended to use new ones(like most people I do reuse them also).

Comment: If they have little holes in the ends, you can use circlip pliers on them to reduce the bending, finger gouging and equipment scratching. Without care, they can still disappear to wherever it is that small parts go to die. As JACK noted, pics of _yours_ will help you get a decent answer.

Comment: We cannot answer this without pictures. I've never met a circlip you could bend, certainly not without some considerable effort & two sets of grips. They're made of really hard spring steel… they'd usually shatter before bending more than a millimetre.

Comment: @FreeMan these appear to be regular C-clips (probably technically E-clips), not circlips, unfortunately.  OP, are you aiming for *nondestructive* removal?

Comment: They do now, @Huesmann, but didn't 1/2 a day ago when we were asking for pics. ;) I'm wondering if taking that particular portion apart is really necessary, but the last time I sprayed paint was with an airbrush about 40 years ago, then again about 20 years ago with a "Wagner Power Sprayer". Both times, I just ran solvent through the sprayer until it came out clear and that was satisfactory. TBH, this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me - _WHY_ does that part need to come off to clean the sprayer?

Comment: @FreeMan The tension spring between the trigger and the handle gets sticky.  The trigger doesn't snap back to a closed position. The trigger starts to get a mushy feel to it. I recall making puddles of finish the last time it got bad. I haven't determined a process that prevents the trigger spring from getting sticky or a way to clean it without removing the clips. I do agree that would be the best solution if one exists.

Comment: @Huesmann I have to put them back on after cleaning.

Comment: @I-Script-Alot that would probably be good info to [edit] into the question to help others help you. If you don't get a good answer here, you may consider asking at [mechanics.se] (or, simply ask for this to be migrated there). Those types of clips are common in automotive applications, so I think you'd get away with it there, even though it's not _technically_ on-topic since it's not really about engine repair.

Comment: Just go buy an e-clip tool, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Neiko-01970A-Clip-Remover-Installer/dp/B000W94UEQ

Answer (score 1):

For all your issues except losing them, use Retaining Clip Pliers.